# App.config for child project not being copied to output

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, app-config

I have a solution with two executable projects.

`Main.exe` is dependent on `Subordinate.exe`.

These projects both have `App.config` files, so in their respective output directories, I have `Main.exe.config` and `Subordinate.exe.config`.

When I build `Main.exe`, `Subordinate.exe` is copied into Main's output directory, but `Subordinate.exe.config` is not.

Is there a standard way to tell Visual Studio to do this?

Comment: An alternative approach is to edit the csproj file for the parent project and use the AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions in a propertygroup. In your case you would add .exe.config to the list of allowed extensions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765686/include-referenced-projects-config-file/9769667#9769667

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on the `Main` project and select `Edit Project File`. Add an `AfterBuild` event:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\Subordinate\bin\$(Configuration)\Subordinate.exe.config" 
          DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: I had already tried this, using `PostBuildEvent`, and found that it was failing on first attempt to build, then succeeding on the second attempt. Turns out in my *real* project the subordinate project was not listed as a dependency of the main project, so it was built after the main project. Once I established the dependency correctly, the post build event worked.  **--** Anyway, I was hoping for a answer that didn't require a AfterBuild/PostBuildEvent, but given that none is forthcoming, I'm marking this as the answer (since it's what I did).

Comment: I'd avoid `PostBuildEvent` at all costs. `AfterBuild` is preferable as it at least build-controlled and traceable.

Comment: I'd just like to add that in VS2012, the macro for configuration (e.g. Debug/Release) is $(ConfigurationName), not $(Configuration).
Also, you may need to include a platform specification (e.g. x86/x64).

You may end up needing to write it like:

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\Subordinate\bin\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)\Subordinate.exe.config" 
          DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />
  </Target>

Comment: It is kinda kludge, isn't it

Answer (score 14):

Another way I found is by adding the app.config file as a linked file to the dependent project, e.g. here you would add a link to Subordinate.exe's app.config into Main.exe's project, and set it to be copied to the output directory when built. You can then change the name of the file that is copied to Main.exe's output directory at build time by editing the `<Link>` element in your project file, something like:

```
<None Include="..\Subordinate.ProjectFolder\app.config">
  <Link>Subordinate.exe.config</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

This has the same issue that you have to hardcode the name of the generated config file, but that's no worse than the `AfterBuild` approach, and I find this method a little more transparent, and it removes the build-order dependency issue that you mentioned.

Comment: Is there any way to make the file appear with the same name as with the link?

Comment: Best solution as the accepted solution is not working on Build Server scenarios :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43280098/1811525) (based on work of @theyetiman). It requires mainly a modification of the project, the `app.config` file belongs to. The *consuming projects* are left unmodified.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="app.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="app.config">
    <Link>$(TargetFileName).config</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Also note, that with Visual Studio 2017 this modification is not necessary any more. If you open a solution with a project containing the above workaround, a warning similar to the following is displayed in the errors window:

> The file 'app.config' could not be added to the project.
>   Cannot add a link to the file ...\app.config.
>   This file is within the project directory tree.

Add a condition comparing `$(VisualStudioVersion)` to avoid this warning and keep backward compatibility:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="app.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '15.0'">
  <None Include="app.config">
    <Link>$(TargetFileName).config</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```